# Split Text at DBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have a field with my SQL database that I need to split after the word DBA appears. I believe it would be a case statement, but I am not sure.

[image]

**Expected Output**

```
S B A SITES INC DBA
SBA SITES INC
```

Comment: Freudian slip in the title?  I get spitting mad at my DBAs from time to time.  In any event, your question needs more info, such as your RDBMS, a sample record, and desired outcome.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server. The sample record is S B A SITES INC DBA SBA SITES INC with the field name Primary_Owner. The desired outcome would be Primary_Owner = S B A SITES INC and the new field would be DBA or Doing_Busines_As = DBA SBA SITES INC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    create table #t1 (primary_owner varchar(100), doing_business_as varchar(100))
insert into #t1 (primary_owner) values ('s b a sites inc dba sites inc')
update #t1 set doing_business_as = substring(primary_owner,charindex('dba',primary_owner),1000 ),primary_owner= left(primary_owner,charindex('dba',primary_owner)-1)

select * from #t1
```